# How to set my web view loaded with already login user -iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, ios-simulator

In my app iam using web view with URL:@"http://www.gmail.com/".

- This web view was loaded when i clicked a button in the main page / home page

  ```
  (IBAction)webClick:(id)sender
   {
  MailViewController *mail = [[MailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MailViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:mail animated:YES];
  }
  ```
- Then the web view was loaded, i used code like thin this in mail view:

  ```
  -(void)viewDidLoad

  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.gmail.com/";
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
      NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
  }
  ```

Here the gmail opened with login page. we need to enter username & password.

What i want is,

- if we already login into my account through gmail application..

  The loaded view directly loades my mail, instead of login page.
- if i didn't already loged in, then show an alert as please login.

How to do it?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, I think the URL you should be loading is `http://mail.google.com/mail`

Other than that, you're not getting normal gmail behavior because UIWebView does not save cookies between app runs, you should try something like this to save them:

```
- (void)saveCookies
{
    NSData         *cookiesData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults    = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: cookiesData forKey: @"cookies"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

and load them back using this:

```
- (void)loadCookies
{
    NSArray             *cookies       = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"cookies"]];
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies)
    {
        [cookieStorage setCookie: cookie];
    }
}
```

Comment: @sheetal try to load from app delegate didFinishLoad , its work perfectly for me

Comment: where do i call save cookies?