# Cocoa Mac App Webview session gets lost

Tags: php, objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

Is it possible to make the PHP session be saved on closing the WebView-App?
I have a Mac App with a WebView and I don't want the user to enter the login data every time he starts the App, because the session is destroyed on closing the App. Is it possible (in PHP on the server, or in Xcode) to change something, that the Session is saved for e.g. one month, and the user is still logged in after restarting the Mac-App?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the cookies for your WebView after logging in and then restore them next time the app loads as shown here:

[How to set my web view loaded with already login user -iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986963/how-to-set-my-web-view-loaded-with-already-login-user-iphone)

That code is for the iPhone but I think it should also work on Mac.

Comment: Well than the login form has to be in the native App. But thanks for your answer though, it will be helpful anyway as I am going to make the login form native (in objective-c) soon.