# Keep losing php session cookie in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cookies, uiwebview

I'm new to the forum and also quite new to iOS Dev. I'm having trouble with a UIWebView, where I keep losing login permission to a HTML form which sets a phpsession cookie (with expiration set to 8h, which works on desktop). It seems the UIWebView throws the cookie away after about an hour or so, instead of 8h. I've read the NSHTTPCookieStorage should take care automatically for cookies, even after app enters background mode or quits.

The NSHTTPCookie looks like this

**NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"PHPSESSID" value:"6f267fdc94c1ce5fcsdgg49b59a8f46b" expiresDate:2013-02-21 01:27:58 +0000 created:2001-01-01 00:00:01 +0000 (1) sessionOnly:FALSE domain:"mydomain.com" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE**

And I do save it on exit/sleep into NSUserDefaults and load it again when coming to foreground/opening app, like recommended here: [How to set my web view loaded with already login user -iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986963/how-to-set-my-web-view-loaded-with-already-login-user-iphone) - Still, I keep losing the login.

Can anyone point me in a direction? Thanks a lot!

I am currently doing this (according to the post underneath):

```
NSURL *lastURL = [[self.webView request] mainDocumentURL];

if (lastURL.absoluteString == NULL) {
    lastURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/"];
}

NSArray *cookiesForDomain = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:lastURL];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookiesForDomain) {

    NSString *cookieString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", [cookie name], [cookie value]];

    [newRequest setValue:cookieString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

    NSLog(@"inserted cookie into request: %@", cookie);

}

[self.webView loadRequest:newRequest];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use in my app many requests and every time when I send a request I get the cookies for the url from `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. I do not use `NSUserDefaults` or something else to store the cookies.

When I send a new request I set the needed cookies my self

```
NSURL *myURL = ....
NSMutableRequest *mutableRequest = ....
NSArray *cookiesToSet = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:myURL];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookiesToSet) {
    [cookieStringToSet appendFormat:@"%@=%@;", cookie.name, cookie.value];
}

if (cookieStringToSet.length) {
    [mutableRequest setValue:cookieStringToSet forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
}
```

And it works

Comment: Will try that immediately! Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm still losing the login even with your solution... any more ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have the cookie in cookiesToSet. (You can put breakpoint in for loop).

Comment: If you see the cookie in with nslog, then it should actually work. To make sure I would make a check on serverside. While you are making that check do not forget to clear cookies(on computer), which you had (maybe)from previous session.

Comment: must be a serverside problem, anyway your answer would solve the problem otherwise, thanks!