# webViewDidFinishLoad: not called in iOS 6 (but called in iOS 5)

Tags: objective-c, ios

The url I'm trying to load is of the form: `@"http://user:password@x.x.x.x/something"`

All I'm doing is creating an NSURLRequest object and loading the request in a web view like this:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://user:password@x.x.x.x/something";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

The page loads fine in iOS 6.0 simulator but not in iOS 5.0 simulator.

What happens in iOS 5.0 is the web view delegate method `webViewDidStartLoad:` is called but either of the methods `webViewDidFinishLoad:` or `webView:didFailLoadWithError:`are not called.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you saying, that all delegate methods are called in iOS5.0, but none are called in iOS 6.0? (is this on a device or simulator? if simulator, reset and restart simulator)

Comment: Check this [UIWebView webViewDidFinishLoad not getting called iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031034/uiwebview-webviewdidfinishload-not-getting-called-ios)

Comment: Also did you try adding `_webView.delegate = self;`?

Comment: Also check this link here: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/15077-uiwebview-not-calling-webviewdidfinishload.html

Comment: All delegate methods are called in iOS 6. On the other hand, only webViewDidStartLoad: is called in iOS 5.

Comment: And yes the web view delegate is set in IB.

Comment: @user1890689: Try setting delegate through coding.

Comment: @ParthBhatt:  Adding _webView.delegate = self; fixed my issue with this.  Thanks!