# iOS: what the reason for webViewDidFinishLoad failure

Tags: ios, webview

Code is simple, So I don't think it's caused by code, I hide some unrelevent code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
    _webView.delegate = self;
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url]];
}  

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"hello,world");
}
```

Once running the app, overtime the website is shown in the webView, but the `NSLog(@"hello,world")` seems not calls every time.(sometimes is called,sometimes is not called).
I have to help web developer to find the bug, and I guess it is caused by some web bug, and I need to know.

Comment: can you provide the url or web source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement below Delegate method to check error

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Error for WEBVIEW: %@", [error description]);
}
```

if problem is not identify possible look this link

[UIWebView webViewDidFinishLoad not getting called iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031034/uiwebview-webviewdidfinishload-not-getting-called-ios)